# SignalR: Unable to connect to the server with any of the available transports

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, signalr

I'm using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client (1.1.0v) in a WPF application targeting .Net 4.6.2. I'm setting up the client like:

```
public class SignalRClient
{
   private readonly HubConnection hubConnection;

   public SignalRClient()
   {
      this.hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                .WithUrl("http://localhost:8089/MyDataHub")
                .Build();
   }

   // I'm calling the following method through a callback function in Autofac container after the DI container is built (but I tried doing this directly in the ctor and I got the same issue).

   public void Initialize()
   {
      Task.Factory.StartNew(
           () => 
           {
               // This is where I get the error.
               this.hubConnection.StartAsync().Wait();
           })
   }
}
```

Server side logs show:

```
16:56:45.380  Info | Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:8089/MyDataHub?id=7qLNfG-iV1Xr3oN_r8U_nA
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:8089/MyDataHub/negotiate  0
16:56:45.540  Info | Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:8089/MyDataHub/negotiate  0
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 11.2669ms 200 application/json
16:56:45.552  Info | Request finished in 11.2669ms 200 application/json
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:8089/MyDataHub/negotiate  0
16:56:45.703  Info | Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:8089/MyDataHub/negotiate  0
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 7.7109ms 200 application/json
16:56:45.703  Info | Request finished in 7.7109ms 200 application/json
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:8089/MyDataHub?id=4TN4k9wZWXsZ5iPyGNKSOA
16:56:45.719  Info | Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:8089/MyDataHub?id=4TN4k9wZWXsZ5iPyGNKSOA
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 6.7847ms 200 application/octet-stream
16:56:45.719  Info | Request finished in 6.7847ms 200 application/octet-stream
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.HubConnectionContext[5]
      Failed connection handshake.
16:56:51.013 Error | Failed connection handshake.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 20012.9772ms 101
16:57:05.393  Info | Request finished in 20012.9772ms 101
```

Error message client-side:

```
Unable to connect to the server with any of the available transports
```

I can't quite understand what this error means and how to fix it. It looks like the server and the client can't agree on a transport?

Note that the server is using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR (2.4.0v). The server project is a Asp.Net Core 2.1 application (I can't change anything here). I'm trying to use the AspNet Core version for client (this seems possible because when I tested with some other .Net Framework WPF and Console projects targeting the exact same framework version, I did not get this error).

1. What are the possible causes for this particular error?
2. Possible fixes.

EDIT:

Route mapping in the server:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
   app.UseSignalR(routes => { routes.MapHub<MyDataHub>("/MyDataHub"); });
}
```

EDIT 2:

MyDataHub.cs class:

```
public class MyDataHub : Hub<IMyDataHub>
{
   public async Task SendMessage(MyData data)
   {
      await this.Clients.All.SendMessage(data);
   }

   // Some other business methods here defined in `IMyDataHub` interface that are meant to be invoked by clients.
}
```

Comment: Did you map your Hub routes in the Startup class?

Comment: @MindSwipe I think so. I added that as an edit to the question.

Comment: Can you also add the code from your `MyDataHub` class?

Comment: I think you're mixing http and https?

Comment: @MindSwipe Updated the question as you requested.

Comment: @PabloRecalde Where do you mean?

Comment: @PabloRecalde it seems like it doesn't matter. I just tried it in my app with http instead of https and the HubConnectionBuilder was smart enough to normalize it for me

Comment: I see, sorry for making noise.

Answer (score 0):

The issue, as it turned out, didn't have much to do with the ode itself. It turned out that different projects in the solution (and there are many!) was using different versions of System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions package (some using 4.3.0 while another using 4.5.1). And there was a binding redirect in the app.config like

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" publicKeyToken="sdhke3jdj" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

This didn't make a lot of sense because I didn't have 4.1.0 anywhere. So, I first consolidated the System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions for the whole solution by upgrading it to 4.5.1. And then deleted the above binding redirect from the app.config file and it started working.